# navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia not work in iphone chrome

Tags: iphone, getusermedia, navigator, mediadevices

I use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` for get media

In chrome of iPhone but not work

Chrome version : 87

My code:

```
// alert fine on safari and error on chrome
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    alert('fine')
} else {
    alert('error')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's true. The Chrome browser on iOS doesn't have all the features of Safari.